# Uninstalling Qtile window manager

Tags: window-manager

I am on Ubuntu 20.04

I am unable to uninstall the qtile window manager. I am trying to uninstall it because I want to re-install it.

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux and if there is any information that is needed I will get it.

Comment: Hi and welcome. How was it installed? How are you trying to remove it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, I installed it through this [guide](http://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/manual/install/index.html#installing-from-source). It's from the official website. I've tried going back into the repo I cloned then doing `pip3 uninstall .` That's the only thing I've tried because that's how I got it in the first place.

Comment: Is that the exact command you use pip3 uninstall . you did not use the file name?

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. Because according to the installation doc I got it with `pip3 install .` so I assumed that to get rid of it I had to do `pip3 uninstall .`

Comment: Strange I have never heard of a command to install or uninstall that did not use a file name.

Comment: So do I just leave it on system and just use something else?

Comment: Is it causing any problems? If not leave it for now maybe some one sees the question and has answer later.

Comment: It's not causing any problems, but it's just near impossible to use the window manager, because almost none of the keyboard shortcuts work as advertised. I can just use Ubuntu normally instead of qtile or just switch to another window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Installed via `pip install .` from github?

Then just type `pip uninstall qtile`
You'll get that prompt:

```
/qtile(master) » pip uninstall qtile                    1 ↵ thetanadu@greenery
Found existing installation: qtile {your_version}
Uninstalling qtile-{your_version}:
  Would remove:
    /home/thetanadu/.local/bin/qtile
    /home/thetanadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libqtile/*
    /home/thetanadu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtile-{your_version}.dist-info/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled qtile-{your_version}
```